# Defining a maskRe in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, validation, extjs, mask

I would like to define a maskRe in javascript that only allows values from 0.002 - 0.1 to be entered in a form, any ideas?

James

On top of this, I would like to create a regex in javascript that only allows values from 0 - 50.00 to be entered in a form, any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please understand that maskRe should be used to filter out invalid *symbols* - but not to validate *value* of an input: `regex` property should be used for this.

You can use both, though:

```
maskRe: /[0-9.]/,
regex: /^0[.](1|0[1-9][0-9]?|00[2-9])$/
```

... or ...

```
regex: /^0[.](1|0[1-9][0-9]*|00[2-9][0-9]*)$/
```

... if you don't need to limit number of digits after the decimal point to three.

UPDATE: for 0 - 50.00 it would be something like this, perhaps...

```
regex: /^(50(?:[.]0+)?|[1-4]?[0-9](?:[.][0-9]+)?)$/
```

Comment: Not sure about maskRe stuff, but that regex allows `0.0` and `0.00`.

Comment: @TylerCrompton Thanks, fixed that. But now I think should the regex really limit the number of digits? I mean, is 0.0021 allowed or not?

Comment: Well, it *is* within the specified range.

Comment: Excellent, thanks for the response. Can you go through what each statement is doing for me? I need to do this for a couple of different 'ranges' of values......